# How to find out how long ago someone checked out document in SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document

I am a regular (non-privileged) user of my company's SharePoint Foundation 2010 system. When a document is checked out, I know how to find out who it is checked out to (hover over green checkout arrow). But I also want to know **how long ago the document was checked out**. Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property [CheckedOutDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.checkedoutdate.aspx) but I'm afraid it is not available anywhere in the User Interface.

As a regular user, I don't think you will be able to find it.

If you can ask an admin or someone else with access, they can find out for you using a small code snippet.

E.g.

```
$item = $web.lists[...].items[...]
$checkedOutDate= $item.File.CheckedOutDate.ToString()
```

Comment: I want to accept this as an answer but I can't since my question was migrated here, and I don't show up as the poster even though I have linked the two site profiles. So, my apologies, have flagged to see if this can be fixed.

Comment: @KAE No Worries! Follow the instructions from [this meta post](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/how-to-get-reputation-credit-for-migrated-questions) and contact the SE staff directly. This is out of scope for moderators unfortunately. Your accounts are linked, but they have different display names and/or username. I don't know if that might be the problem?!

Comment: Not sure if it was because I changed to a consistent display name, or because SE directly changed it, but now I can accept the answer. Should I delete these comments?

Comment: @KAE..Just Chill!!..:D