# How to get all checked out files and when they were checked out

Tags: 2013, rest

Trying to figure out a way to use REST or JSOM to find all checkedout files in a library. I can use a list view to show which files are checked out and by whom, but there is no way to see how long ago it was checked out and I need this information. I need to do this from the client side/in-browser.

I found [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149571/how-to-find-out-how-long-ago-someone-checked-out-document-in-sharepoint-foundati) about viewing the **CheckedOutDate** column, but the approved answer doesn't make sense to me and I assume it is something that you need central admin access.

```
$item = $web.lists[...].items[...]
$checkedOutDate= $item.File.CheckedOutDate.ToString()
```

I thought I might try REST and found [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/How-to-get-all-the-checked-out-files-in-a-library-with-rest/td-p/31488) which talks about this endpoint.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=CheckoutUserId ne null
```

But that throws `Column CheckoutUserId does not exist` error. But when I remove the filter I can see the CheckoutUserId in the list of columns returned and when I check the **Fields** endpoint I do see the field and saw that it also has a different name **CheckedOutUserId**. And I am able to filter on that property.

After that I've got a list of checked out files, but I still can't get when it was checked out. I don't see that field anywhere. Does anyone know how to get that date?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sending this as a GET? It should be.

This query worked for me: (same as your example)

```
/sites/training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileDirRef,Title,CheckoutUserId&$filter=CheckoutUserId ne null
```

The `$select` clause is for clarity, but using just the `$filter` clause alone works fine.

I don't think the `CheckedOutDate` property is accessible via REST for the library request.

Comment: Is there some other way to get the CheckedOutDate?

Comment: Oh and CheckoutUserId throws an error that it doesn't exist.

Comment: you need to $expand=CheckoutUserId and somehow work with CheckedOutDate too

Comment: "CheckoutUserId throws an error that it doesn't exist"  Just to confirm... you are using SharePoint 2013? Are you testing with a FullControl account?

Comment: SP 2013 on prem. I'm a site collection admin and have full control. I see CheckoutUserId, but when I try to filter on it it throws an error. I don't see CheckedOutUserId, but can filter on that. But what I really need is the date!